# How do I use a pattern to unlock the phone screen?

Tags: lock-screens, pattern-lock

Is there a way to set up my lock screen so that I can draw a pattern to unlock the phone? That way, only I can unlock it again. At the moment, my phone automatically locks the screen, but you just slide to unlock it. Because of that, any one can unlock my phone, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the home screen hit the menu button, then choose Settings > Location & Security and from there you should have an option to set up a patter or pin based screenlock.  The pattern lock will give you the option to create your own pattern on the 3x3 grid:
[image]

If you want to be able to draw a completely random pattern, Cyanogenmod 6.2 has the option to draw any invisible Gesture to unlock the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much. All along it was within android itself. I wasted a lot of time looking for an app that would do this. Once again, thansk : )

Comment: @Jay: Which is a large part of the reason we strongly encourage people to ask for solutions ("How do I...?") and not ask for apps ("Is there an app that...?")